# I want to hover an element and change style of another element which is just after the hovered one in tailwind

Tags: tailwind-css

I have an icon and some text after the icon. I want to hover on that icon and want to translate the text in x axis. I know how I can do it in CSS, but I want to know if there is a way to do it in Tailwind.

```html
    <nav class="absolute right-80 top-32">
      <ul class="items border p-4 rounded-full flex-col items-center content-center">
          <li class="item text-2xl pt-3 hover:text-sky-400 cursor-pointer home-icon"><i class="fas fa-home"></i></li>
             <p class="home-text hidden">Home</p>
          <li class="item text-2xl pt-3 hover:text-sky-400 cursor-pointer"><i class="fas fa-user"></i></li>
          <li class="item text-2xl pt-3 hover:text-sky-400 cursor-pointer"><i class="fas fa-graduation-cap"></i></li>
          <li class="item text-2xl pt-3 hover:text-sky-400 cursor-pointer"><i class="fas fa-briefcase"></i></li>
          <li class="item text-2xl pt-3 hover:text-sky-400 cursor-pointer"><i class="fas fa-newspaper"></i></li>
          <li class="item text-2xl pt-3 hover:text-sky-400 cursor-pointer"><i class="fas fa-envelope"></i></li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
```

Comment: Can you include the text in your  `<li>` (e.g. in a `<span>`)? If so you can give your `<li class='group'>` and use the `group-hover` pseudo-class: `<span class='group-hover:translate-x-10'>Home</span>`.

Comment: it's not working